# Swift: Refactor switch statement inside of another switch statement

Tags: swift, struct, enums, switch-statement, refactoring

I have a method that calculates a new score. The method below works, but the problem is the code itself looks like it can be cleaned up significantly. I just don't what would be the best way to do it. I assign `scoreCount`an integer depending on filterString and the enum `individualScoreState`

```
func calculateScore(count: Int, filterString: String, individualScoreState: IndividualScores) -> Int {
    var scoreCount: Int = 0
    var results = Results()

    switch filterString {
    case "ScoreA":
        switch individualScoreState {
        case .firstScore:
            scoreCount = results.firstScoreACount
        case .secondScore:
            scoreCount = results.secondScoreACount
        default:
            scoreCount = results.scoreACount
        }
    case @"ScoreB":
        switch individualScoreState {
        case .firstScore:
            scoreCount = results.firstScoreBCount
        case .secondScore:
            scoreCount = results.secondScoreBCount
        default:
            scoreCount = results.scoreBCount
        }
    default:
        switch individualScoreState {
        case .firstScore:
            scoreCount = results.firstScoreACount + results.firstScoreBCount
        case .secondScore:
            scoreCount =  results.secondScoreACount + results.secondScoreBCount
        default:
            scoreCount = results.scoreACount + results.scoreBCount
        }
    }

   return count / scoreCount
}
```

// Results struct

```
struct Results {
    var scoreACount = 0
    var scoreBCount = 0

    var firstScoreACount = 0
    var firstScoreBCount = 0

    var secondScoreACount = 0
    var secondScoreBCount = 0 
}
```

There might be a cleaner way to handle this. Perhaps a way to combine the two switch cases?

Edit: Forgot to mention this `results` is an instance of a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
let notB = filterString != "ScoreB" ? 1 : 0
let notA = filterString != "ScoreA" ? 1 : 0

switch individualScoreState {
case .firstScore:
    scoreCount = notB * results.firstScoreACount + notA * results.firstScoreBCount
case .secondScore:
    scoreCount = notB * results.secondScoreACount + notA * results.secondScoreBCount
default:
    scoreCount = notB * results.scoreACount + notA * results.scoreBCount
}
```

---

The `@` in case @"ScoreB" is used in the Objective-C but not in Swift for String literals, just remove it.